# Why must C# operator overloads be static?

Tags: c#, c++, static, operator-overloading, language-design

Why does C# require operator overloads to be static methods rather than member functions (like C++)? (Perhaps more specifically: what was the design motivation for this decision?)

Comment: C++ allows operators to be free (ie. non member) functions. But C# decided to put a Stalinian ban on free functions, so you have to put static there.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Take a look at [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2007/05/14/why-are-overloaded-operators-always-static-in-c.aspx).

A couple of reasons, the primary seeming to be to preserve operator symmetry (such that the left hand side of a binary operation does not get special treatment, as being responsible for dispatching the operation).

Comment: @Frederic Here you go https://web.archive.org/web/20150906063729/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/05/14/why-are-overloaded-operators-always-static-in-c.aspx

Answer (score 37):

This has been answered in excruciating detail by Eric Lippert in a [blog post](https://ericlippert.com/2007/05/14/why-are-overloaded-operators-always-static-in-c/) that has since been removed. Here is the [archived version](https://web.archive.org/web/20151204153738/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/05/14/why-are-overloaded-operators-always-static-in-c.aspx).

There is also another subtler point about value types and instance operators. Static operators make this kind of code possible:

```
class Blah {

    int m_iVal;

    public static Blah operator+ (Blah l, int intVal)
    {
        if(l == null)
            l = new Blah();
        l.m_iVal += intVal;
        return l;
    }
}

//main
Blah b = null;
b = b + 5;
```

So you can invoke the operator, even though the reference is null. This wouldn't be the case for instance operators.

Comment: gonna give the green check to @Sapph just cause you've got waaaay more rep :)

Comment: lol i saw the rep go up and then down for like a second. Well deserved, Sapph put more effort into the answer.

Comment: IMHO, don't do this. Looks like a bad design, because this behavior seems to be unexpected.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps its best to think why should the methods not be static. There is no need for state and hence this.

Comment: There might not be a state benefit but having virtual operator overloading would be cool. The state-thing is not the reason why it is not available in C#.