# Why implicit operator has to be static?

Tags: c#

I have a class named `FloatPlugIn`. I want user to be able to do things like

```
FloatPlugIn x = new FloatPlugIn();
x.Minimum = -100;
x.Maximum = 100;

float y = 123;
x = y;
```

That is why I decided to add `implicit operator` to my class

```
public static implicit operator FloatPlugIn(float p)
{
    return new FloatPlugIn() { Default = p };
}
```

Problem is that implicit operator has to be static that is why during conversion new instance of my class is created. As a result I am loosing all the information that was located inside of "old" instance.

Is there a way to fix that? I want float value to be applied to existing instance, not to completely replace it.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273743/static-implicit-operator. It is a conversion operator which enables conversion implicitly.

Comment: You can't "add" with an assignment operator. The C# semantics match what you'd expect to happen if you read this code as an innocent developer, whereas your intent is to subvert them. Why not overload `+` instead?

Comment: _I want float value to be added to existing instance..._ Wouldn't an `Add` method be more appropiate then?

Comment: How about doing `x.Default = y;` ?

Comment: It does sound like you want to set a property on an existing instance.

Comment: Which "old" instance you refer to? The `FloatPlugin`? Casting will usually *create* an entirely new instance (nless you cast into a base-class or an interface). What you want is to *modifiy* an existing one.

Comment: @HimBromBeere in my code current (old) instance of 'x' variable would be replaced with a new one during the assignment.

Comment: Exactly. An *assignment* assigns a **completey independent** instance, so of course you lose all the information of that "old" instance. Thus you don´t want an *assignement*, but a *modification*.

Comment: @JeroenMostert - He's trying to compose the values, not perform a mathematical addition. The word "added" can mean "composition", not just "addition".

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thank you, you are right - I changed it from "add" to "apply" to make myself clear

Comment: @walruz - If you want it applied then it is probably just a property that you need to create.

Comment: @Enigmativity I just don't see why implicit conversion has to be static.

Comment: @walruz - I don't think you're understanding what conversion does - it's not casting - it **must** create a new instance. It only makes sense to make it non-static if it were only updating the existing instance.

Comment: @Enigmativity Thank you, I think you have just answered my question. Please consider re-arranging your last comment as an answer.

Comment: @walruz - Done.

Comment: I think the more fundamental problem here is that float is most likely too small to hold a FloatPlugIn's data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you're understanding what conversion does - it's not casting - it must create a new instance. It only makes sense to make it non-static if it were only updating the existing instance.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better in this case if you either use `x.Default = y;` or if you create a constructor that takes the float like this:

```
// Constructor
public FloatPlugIn(float p)
{
    Default = p;
}
```

*Usage:*

```
float y = 123;
FloatPlugIn x = new FloatPlugIn(y);
```

Comment: Sorry, that is not answering my question. I would rather prefer x.Default = y

Comment: If you look carefully, you'll see that x.Default = y is the first alternative in my answer :-)

Comment: Right :) But I wanted user to be able to treat x variable just like an ordinary float while x still owning some extra information inside.

Answer (score 0):

The semantics of the [assignment operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/assignment-operator) requires that behavior. In fact:

> The assignment operator (=) stores the value of its right-hand operand in the storage location, property, or indexer denoted by its left-hand operand and returns the value as its result. The operands must be of the same type (or the right-hand operand must be implicitly convertible to the type of the left-hand operand).

It is not the purpose of the implicit conversion operator to *modify* a destination value—note that there may not be *any* such destination value, such as in case you pass the value to a parameter of a method.

> I want float value to be added to existing instance, not to completely replace it.

If you want an *addition* (in whatever specific sense that would mean in your case), consider overriding the addition `+` operator, which in turn has effect on the [addition assignment `+=` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/addition-assignment-operator). However, you won't eliminate the creation of a new `FloatPlugIn` instance anyway.

Consider you'd have the following method in `FloatPlugIn`, which would modify an existing instance:

```
public void Add(float f)
{
    // do whatever 'addition' means in your case
}
```

Then the `+` operator should work like this:

```
public static FloatPlugIn operator +(FloatPlugIn a, float b)
{
    FloatPlugIn result = a.Clone(); // here Clone() denotes any custom method that creates a copy of that instance
    result.Add(b);
    return b;
}
```

In your code, the following would work then:

```
FloatPlugIn x = new FloatPlugIn();
x.Minimum = -100;
x.Maximum = 100;

float y = 123;
x += y; // a new instance is created, but the 'addition' logic is preserved
```

Also, the same will intuitively work in case of passing a value to a method call:

```
ProcessMyFloatPlugin(x + 123.0f);
```

You can see that *it is a really good idea* to create a new instance of `FloatPlugIn` as a result of an operator. Otherwise, an in-place modification of `x` would be, in fact, a nasty side-effect, completely unexpected by any other developer. Note that if performance (avoiding dynamic memory allocations) is a concern, consider using `struct`s.

Comment: I believe you've misunderstood what the OP meant by "added". He's not suggesting a mathematical addition operation, instead he is asking to somehow compose the float value with the existing instance.

Comment: @Enigmativity: the "beauty" of operator overloading (some would call it a curse) is that you're not bound by mathematics. `Foo operator+(Foo foo, float p)` can do basically whatever you want -- it could even return `foo` after modifying it, although that subverts the semantics so bad that you'll likely get into trouble using it. That's not to say a simple, explicit instance method couldn't be the more appropriate solution here -- it depends on what kind of thing `FloatPlugIn` is, and if "adding" floats to it makes sense.

Comment: @Enigmativity I don't think so. Whatever the OP means by 'addition', be it. The `+` operator just works well to represent an 'addition' in a common sense. See my updated answer that provides a specific example now. If it's clear now, an un-downvote would be welcome then :))