# How to determine whether a variable type supports given operators in C#

Tags: c#, operators

I have this problem:

I want to make a generic class which will support the +, -, *, / operators. For example a Matrice class. The problem is, some data types support all of the above operators, some support part of them, some don't support them at all. I want to make my class recognize which of the above operators are supported and if some of them are not supported I want to see a **COMPILE TIME** error.

Example:

`Matrice<int>`: we can do +, -, /, * because an int has these operators overloaded/defined

`Matrice<string>`: we can do only +, since string has only + overloaded/defined and if we try
`Matrice<string> a = new Matrice<string>;`
`Matrice<string> b = new Matrice<string>;`
`Matrice<string> c = a*b;`
we should get a **COMPILE TIME** error

`Matrice<CustomClass>`: if CustomClass has only / and + overloaded (for example) the `Matrice<CustomClass>` should support only / and + operators

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not possible. Operator overloading is static, so you can't use an interface or inheritance to ensure your operators are considered. See more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603940/c-sharp-interface-cannot-contain-operators

Comment: is it possible to define a where clause for a given `<T>` so that you can force an interface for + - / * operators?

Comment: @bas - Only for `CustomClass`. There'd be no way to apply that back to the builtin types.

Comment: @MPelletier Yeah lol should have pressed the button "1 more comment" before pressing enter.... :) I can remember that we tried to achieve something similar (also in regard of a generic Matrix class) and we coulnd't get it to work either. Is that a deliberate thing or something that is 'forgotten' in the language? some kind of base type for operator overloading

Comment: @bas It's been asked countless times and the .NET designers are adamant about it. Even *the* Eric Lippert chipped in, arguing that this would not be ideal.

Comment: Oh well, I'll have to make a work-around. Thanks for the answers guys. I would mark this as answered, but there are only comments....

Comment: @MarioStoilov Not anymore ;)

Comment: @MPelletier: Don't get me wrong: I would really like it if there were a slam-dunk solution to this frequently-pointed-out shortcoming of the language. The situation however is that making the language really awesome for the small number of developers who are writing genericized math libraries is quite expensive, and that limited budget could be spent on features that benefit larger classes of developers. Every solution proposed so far has been either too weak to motivate the change, or required too much expensive work in the CLR type system.

Comment: @EricLippert that makes sense. But is it that much work? I understand that it is not as simple as 'extract interface', but it is an *addition* to the interfaces right? The existing 'legacy' of the .net framework would not be affected right? Are there any online insights regarding this feature, or is that internal to microsoft only?

Comment: @bas: The problem is how to do the feature in a sufficiently general way that solves more than just the "I want to write trivial `Sum` and `Average` without code duplication" problem but without becoming as general as, say, Haskell type classes. Finding that middle ground is a tricky design problem.

Comment: @EricLippert I didn't expect you to show up. :) The money/complexity factor is the most compelling argument, but I often see less compelling ones. One being that end user implementation would be too hazardous.

Comment: @MPelletier: Making it easy on end users is indeed another tricky part of the design. Another is that when you get down to it, the sorts of restrictions you want to impose become hard to represent in type systems. How would you say, for example, I want T to be any type that implements a *commutative* `+` operator? (Which of course brings to mind the joke: what's purple and commutes?)

Comment: @MPelletier: The answer is of course: an Abelian grape.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible. Operator overloading is static, so you can't use an interface or inheritance to ensure your operators are considered. See more [here](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/6603940/)

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible in C#.  You will need to use some sort of traditional method or delegate to indicate how to "add" "subtract", etc. for each item.