# C# - interfaces cannot contain operators

Tags: c#, .net, interface, operator-overloading

**Question: Can C# interfaces contain operators?**

From searching, the answer I have found is **no**.
For example, [C# interface cannot contain operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603940/c-sharp-interface-cannot-contain-operators)

However, in Andrew Troelsen's book "Pro C# 5.0 and the .Net 4.5 framework" he makes the following statement

> Alas, operator constraints are not supported under the current version of C#. However, it is possible
>   (albeit it requires a bit more work) to achieve the desired effect by defining an interface that supports
>   these operators (**C# interfaces can define operators!**) and then specifying an interface constraint of the
>   generic class.

The sentence in bold is what puzzles me. Indeed, when I try the following

```
using System;

interface MathOps<T> where T : class
{
    static T operator+(T a, T b);
}

class MyClass : MathOps<MyClass>
{
    int x;

    public MyClass(int n = 0)
    {
        x = n;
    }

    public static MyClass operator+(MyClass a, MyClass b)
    {
        return new MyClass(a.x + b.x);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Add<T>(ref T a, ref T b) where T : class, MathOps<T>
    {
        return a + b;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

    }
}
```

The compiler throws the following back at me

```
error CS0567: Interfaces cannot contain operators
```

So the case kinda seems settled. But why does Mr Troelsen write the way he does? Am i missing/misinterpreting something?

Thanks.

Comment: Interfaces cannot contain static methods.  Not that removing the *static* keyword gets you anywhere.  Beware that books like that tend to suffer from poor editing, it *might* have been possible in .NET 1.x.  The CLR doesn't care that an interface has an operator, it is just a method with a funny name.  A minor hint that might have been the case is that the offline copy of MSDN I use does not have CS0567 in the index.  You are wasting your time on this.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks, yeah I agree with you that it looks like the book needs some more editing. I won't put more effort into this, interfaces can't contain operators, period.

Answer (score 0):

One key to remember is that, as far as I know, it's not so much that an interface cannot define operators (though that is true) but that interfaces cannot define statics, which is frustrating but also logical.

Comment: I'm curious why the downvote? I'm not arguing against, but a downvote without a comment doesn't help me to learn anything. :) And also, I *think* that what I said is true.

Comment: This has obviously changed with C# 8. Interfaces can now define static methods, but still cannot define [operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0567)