# Does such an interface in c# exists: IADD<T>?

Tags: c#

I would like to write a generic sum function on an enumerable of elements that have the + operator implemented.

```
public T Add<T>(IEnumerable<t> list)=> list.Aggregate((x,y)=>x+y)
```

I need to say that T implement the + operator with an element of the same type.

```
with T:IADD<T>
```

I didn't find if such an interface exists in c#

Comment: `Linq` `.Sum()` [system.linq.enumerable.sum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum?view=net-5.0)

Comment: [C# interfaces cannot contain operators](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6603940/215552)

Comment: @RyanWilson I don't think so: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum?view=net-5.0 .It works with any type only if you give it a function from this type to a number.
What I want: I have my own my volume with the + operator. I want to use Add with a list of volume and it returns a volume

Comment: Why not just overload the `+` operator of the `Volume` class then? Why an interface? Both the overloaded operator and the interface would require a class-specific implementation, right? So right now I don't see the advantages of an interface here.

Comment: @RyanWilson Can you flash out your example a bit more? What kind of usage are you trying ideally to achieve in the end?

Comment: @Nenad I think you tagged the wrong person. I'm not the OP.

Answer (score 2):

No. There is a [proposal to add something like this](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/main/proposals/static-abstracts-in-interfaces.md), but (by the location) it is just "under consideration", and has not been earmarked for vNext (C# 10 at time of writing).