# Comparison to null evaluates to true for both expr == null and expr != null

Tags: c#, .net, null

I am seeing something very strange, which I cannot explain. I am guessing some edge case of C# which I am not familiar with, or a bug in the runtime / emitter?

I have the following method:

```
public static bool HistoryMessageExists(DBContext context, string id)
{
    return null != context.GetObject<HistoryMessage>(id);
}
```

While testing my app, I see it is misbehaving - it is returning `true` for objects I know do not exist in my db. So I stopped at the method and in Immediate, I ran the following:

```
context.GetObject<HistoryMessage>(id)
null
null == context.GetObject<HistoryMessage>(id)
true
null != context.GetObject<HistoryMessage>(id)
true
```

`GetObject` is defined like so:

```
public T GetObject<T>(object pk) where T : DBObject, new()
{
    T rv = Connection.Get<T>(pk);

    if (rv != null)
    {
        rv.AttachToContext(this);
        rv.IsInserted = true;
    }

    return rv;
}
```

Interestingly, when casting the expression to `object`, the comparison is evaluated correctly:

```
null == (object)context.GetObject<HistoryMessage>(id)
true
null != (object)context.GetObject<HistoryMessage>(id)
false
```

<s>There is no equality operator overriding.</s>

*Edit:* It turns out there is an operator overload, which was incorrect. But then why would the equality evaluate correctly in the internal method generic `GetObject`, where `rv` is of type `HistoryMessage` in this case.

```
public class HistoryMessage : EquatableIdentifiableObject
{
    public static bool HistoryMessageExists(DBContext context, string id)
    {
        var rv = context.GetObject<HistoryMessage>(id);
        bool b = rv != null;
        return b;
    }

    public static void AddHistoryMessage(DBContext context, string id)
    {
        context.InsertObject(new HistoryMessage { Id = id });
    }
}

public abstract partial class EquatableIdentifiableObject : DBObject, IObservableObject
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [PrimaryKey]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    //...
}

public abstract partial class EquatableIdentifiableObject
{
    //...

    public static bool operator ==(EquatableIdentifiableObject self, EquatableIdentifiableObject other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(self, null))
        {
            return ReferenceEquals(other, null);
        }

        return self.Equals(other);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(EquatableIdentifiableObject self, EquatableIdentifiableObject other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(self, null))
        {
            return !ReferenceEquals(other, null);
        }

        return !self.Equals(other);
    }
}

public abstract class DBObject
{
    [Ignore]
    protected DBContext Context { get; set; }

    [Ignore]
    internal bool IsInserted { get; set; }

    //...
}
```

What is going on here?

Comment: Does `HistoryMessage` implement the equality operators?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen No, no overriding. Forgot to write in the question that there is no operator overriding here.

Comment: Not even on any of the base classes for `HistoryMessage`?

Comment: In any case, can you show us `HistoryMessage`?

Comment: If you decompile the project you can spot if there is actually operator overloading in play. Try [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) for a free decompiler. If there is a basic reference check the comparison should be implemented by the `ceq` instruction, if there is operator overloading in play it would look like `call SomeClass.op_Equality`. You can also spot this in [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) which is where I tried this.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Good idea, will test. Thanks

Comment: Another reason for this behavior could be a racing condition or a bug in `GetObject` that makes consecutive calls return different results. Cache `context.GetObject<HistoryMessage>(id)` to a local variable and *then* check for `null` equality and see if the issue persists.

Comment: I suspect `Connection.Get<T>()` is behaving wrong, I also agree to @InBetween, sometimes caching logic or any other logic may act weird that even few microsecond in execution will make a difference. Can you post code for `Connection.Get<T>()` ?

Comment: They are returning the same result. Assigning to a local variable results in the same behavior.

Comment: @AkashKava Why is then the internal `if (rv != null)` comparison evaluated correctly?

Comment: @LeoNatan how do you know the internal comparison evaluated correctly? If `rv` is `null`, it will simply return `null`, for first time, there is no distinguishing factor here. Try to put log in there, to prove that it is behaving strange as well.

Comment: @LeoNatan: does any multi-threading take place?

Comment: @AkashKava The internal comparison evaluates correctly, because otherwise there would be a null pointer exception. Adding debug log proves that the internal method behaves correctly.

Comment: @Dennis Right now there isn't any multithreading.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Hmm, after looking CIL I saw there was operator overloading, which I later found. But in that case, what I don't understand is why in the internal, generic method `GetObject`, the overloaded `!=` operator was not called for `rv != null`?

Comment: Where was the operator declared? In which class?

Comment: In any case, it is impossible to answer why a method behaves the way it does without seeing the method, so if you want to know why the operator didn't fail in the GetObject method, you're going to have to post the operator overload method.

Comment: It is defined as a `partial` of the superclass of `HistoryMessage`. Get object has `HistoryMessage` as its generic type. I will post tomorrow the classes.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Please see edit. I've added my classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- As you already clarified, the `==` operator failed for your type because you had an overload that was incorrect.
- When casting to object, the `==` operator worked correctly since it was `object's` implementation of `==` that was used and not `EquatableIdentifiableObject's`.
- In the method `GetObject` the operator evaluates correctly because it is not `EquatableIdentifiableObject's` implementation of `==` that is being used. In C# generics are resolved at run-time (at least in the sense that is relevant here) and not at compile time. Note that `==` is static and not virtual.  So the type `T` is resolved at run-time but the call to `==` has to be resolved at compile time. At compile time when the compiler resolves `==` it will not know to use `EquatableIdentifiableObject's` implementation of `==`. Since the type T has this constraint: `where T : DBObject, new()`, `DBObject's` implementation (if any) will be used. If `DBObject` does not define `==` then the implementaion of the first base class that does so (up to `object`) will be used.

A few more comments about `EquatableIdentifiableObject's` implementation of `==`:

- You could replace this part:

```
if (ReferenceEquals(self, null))
{
     return ReferenceEquals(other, null);
}
```

with:

```
// If both are null, or both are the same instance, return true.
if (object.ReferenceEquals(h1, h2))
{
    return true;
}
```

- It would be more robust to replace

```
public static bool operator !=(EquatableIdentifiableObject self, EquatableIdentifiableObject other)
{
    ...
}
```

with:

```
public static bool operator !=(EquatableIdentifiableObject self, EquatableIdentifiableObject other)
{
    return !(self == other);
}
```

- The way you define the signature for `==` is slightly misleading. The first parameter is named `self` and the second is named `other`. That would be ok if `==` was an instance method. Since it is a static method, the name `self` is a bit misleading. Better names would be `o1` and `o2` or something along this  line so that the two operands are treated on a more equal footing.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'm guessing operators are not virtual because they are static. Any idea why operators are implemented as static? Is it because of the null edge case?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018108/why-must-c-sharp-operator-overloads-be-static

Comment: BTW, if you write your own generic method and want to benefit of the virtual aspect of comparison you can do so by overwriting the virtual `Equals` and calling that.

Comment: Actually, I do have it overwritten. That's why I initially thought I had no operator overloads (not a big fan). It seems here I find more reasons not to like them.

Answer (score 1):

There can be several overloads of `operator ==(...)` as you now know. Some of them can be C# built-in overloads, and others can be user-defined operators.

If you hold the mouse over the `!=` or `==` symbol in Visual Studio, it will show you what overload is chosen by overload resolution (up till VS2013 it would only show it if the chosen overload was actually a user-defined one, in VS2015 it will show it in all cases I believe).

The ***binding*** of `==` (i.e. which overload to call) is fixed statically at compile-time. The is nothing dynamic or virtual about it. So if you have:

```
public T SomeMethod<T>() where T : SomeBaseClass
{
  T rv = ...;

  if (rv != null)
  {
```

then which overload of `!=` to use will be fixed, at compile-time, with usual overload resolution (including a few special rules for `==`). The `rv` has type `T` which is known to be a reference type eqaul to or deriving from `SomeBaseClass`. So the best overload is chosen based on that. That might be the `operator !=(object, object)` overload (built-in) if `SomeBaseClass` does not define (or "inherit") an appropriate overload.

At run-time, then, even if the actual substitution for `T` happens to be a more specific type `SomeEqualityOverloadingClass` (that satisfies the constraint of course), that does not mean a new overload resolution will happen at run-time!

This is different from the `virtual` method `.Equals(object)`.

In C#, generics do not work like templates, and they are not like `dynamic`.

If you really want `dynamic` overload resolution (*binding* at run-time instead of at compile-time), it is allowed to say `if ((dynamic)rv != null)`.